# cannot connect server when is in android phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, network-programming

I'm working on a google cardboard project (Unity that will run on android phone)

I created a server in the Unity program that opens like this:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
listener.Start();
TcpListener client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Everything on backgroundworkers and nice things.
Then I connect from another piece of code running in a PC (WPF C# code). If Im running both programs in the PC I can connect flawlessly but when I compile for android and move the server to the phone, I cannot connect to it from the PC

When I try to perform:

```
 host = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.1.8");
```

I get: Unknown host

The IP is correct (I made the server in the phone show it on screen, and I can ping to it) I think the problem is more related to the thing being in a different machine than to the fat that it is compiled for android but nevertheless.. here you have the full story.

Any help ?

Comment: Don't use DNS. DNS is for retrieving an ip address from a host name. You have already an ip address. So use that for your client socket. Make it more like host ="192.168.1.8";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what it was becauseI moved to UDP messages, and now it works.